# Shade Background iOS Popup

Tags: ios, background, xamarin.ios, uialertview

I have two specific questions.

Background Info:
-Using MonoTouch (although I can understand some Objective-C)

First, how would I make a view appear that doesn't take up the whole screen (like a popup, but I don't want to use UIAlertView or anything like that).

Also, how would I make the background a little darker (to contrast between the popup and the original view)?

Appreciate any help anyone can give!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by presenting a different view controller. A View controller (along with it's view) always take up the entire screen and even if the view is smaller, the rest of the screen will be filled with black.

What you describe is easy to do with a hidden View (let's name it panelView) inside your parent view. The panelView should have Hidden=true to begin with and then you can show it by changing this attribute, or maybe animate it's Alpha property to show it slowly.

To achieve the effect with the darker background, you could use a background image for panelView. It should have an alpha channel so that around the center the background view shows through, while it is solid in the center where the content is.

Let me know if you need more info, I have implemented this in an app :
http://obliviusapps.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/4.png?w=370&h=